# Which layout in android studio to use for placing precisely clip arts

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio

I have a viewpager that recreate parallax effect using ViewPager.PageTransformer()

I have a clip art made of several pieces (clouds, tree etc...) that i have to place very precisely on a layout of one of my fragment, so can animate them later independently , but i'm unable to place any item precisely. On a relative layout, it seems that each time i move one items with the mouse, it goes either right , left, or top etc.., i want to be able to place them pixels by pixels, a bit like a puzzle

Is there any any layout (mspaint style) i could use that would let me place freely my item using my mouse for example, without having to obey any rules of placement ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to use `RelativeLayout` in Android Studio to place items precisely. The images to tend to "snap" along grid lines when close, but I think that with careful mouse movement you can make it work. This will be very dependent upon the screen size and will not scale up/down well since it is using margins, but it may be what you need.

Here is the layout I tested with in Android Stdio 2.1. I hope this helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="219dp"
    android:layout_height="219dp"
    android:background="#00FF00"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="219dp"
    android:layout_height="219dp"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="53dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Cheticamp, thanks for your answer,  yes finally this is what i ended up doing, using RelativeLayout and a nice piece of patience, it worked , but what a pain :/

Comment: You are right - works but a pain. If this is something that you will need to do on a regular basis, you might look for another tool that can generate the layouts more easily. I don't know of any, offhand, but one may exist.

Comment: I won't be doing parallax on viewpagers everyday (hopefully), i will be fine 'till a client ask again for this function, thx :)